# systemd-logind.service doesn't work (NAMESPACE error)

Tags: debian, systemd, lxc, logind

The problem that occurred to me goes as follows.

I became the admin of a recently launched Linux machine. The specs are:

```
Kernel: 5.13.19-1-pve
OS: Debian GNU/Linux 11 (bullseye)
```

At first, I noticed the slow login times through SSH (30-60 seconds). So I checked it using `ssh -v [address]` and I realized that it gets stuck at: `debug1: pledge: network`. I read that the problem is probably with `systemd-logind.service` so I checked it:

```
$ sudo systemctl status systemd-logind.service 
* systemd-logind.service - User Login Management
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/systemd-logind.service; static)
    Drop-In: /etc/systemd/system/systemd-logind.service.d
             `-override.conf
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Thu 2021-12-23 10:37:18 UTC; 3min 52s ago
       Docs: man:sd-login(3)
             man:systemd-logind.service(8)
             man:logind.conf(5)
             man:org.freedesktop.login1(5)
    Process: 1072 ExecStart=/lib/systemd/systemd-logind (code=exited, status=226/NAMESPACE)
   Main PID: 1072 (code=exited, status=226/NAMESPACE)
        CPU: 1ms

Dec 23 10:37:18 h133 systemd[1]: systemd-logind.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 5.
Dec 23 10:37:18 h133 systemd[1]: Stopped User Login Management.
Dec 23 10:37:18 h133 systemd[1]: systemd-logind.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
Dec 23 10:37:18 h133 systemd[1]: systemd-logind.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Dec 23 10:37:18 h133 systemd[1]: Failed to start User Login Management.
```

Indeed, I have a problem with this service. So I scoped the web trying to find an answer and everyone says the same: **enable lxc nesting**. And that's okay although... it seems that I don't have the `lxc` installed on this machine!

I tried to find any `lxc` config files and the only one I found is:

```
$ sudo find ./ -name "*lxc*"
./dev/.lxc-boot-id
```

So it seems I have a single file connected to the `lxc` even though this package is not installed. The file contains only the id which is the same as in `/proc/sys/kernel/random/boot_id` file.

*BTW.* I also tried another solution. I opened `/lib/systemd/system/systemd-logind.service` and tried to change these settings:

```
PrivateTmp=yes
ProtectControlGroups=yes
ProtectKernelModules=yes
ProtectSystem=strict
```

To:

```
PrivateTmp=no
ProtectControlGroups=no
ProtectKernelModules=no
ProtectSystem=no
```

And then I rebooted the machine. Sadly, it didn't help, `systemd-logind.service` doesn't start.

Does anyone have some tips for me? What can I do to fix this?

Comment: You need to look for LXC configuration on the host computer, not on the guest.